# OjAlgo Gurobi integration

Tags: maven, pom.xml, gurobi, ojalgo

I have a working OjAlgo solver for ILPs and I wish to integrate it with Gurobi (on an academic license). This is the repository where the author explains how to integrate Gurobi with OjAlgo https://github.com/optimatika/ojAlgo-extensions/tree/develop/ojAlgo-gurobi
However, the POM declares properties that need paths to Gurobi 7.5.1 jar and binaries. However, this version of Gurobi is not available anymore from Gurobi website. Is it possible to use Gurobi 8.1.0 (this is the version that I have)?
If yes, can someone please elaborate how based on the instructions on the Github page above. Specifically, after I added the dependency mentioned in the page to my project, how can I do the following step from the above Github page.

That POM declares properties that are paths to where the jar and native binaries are installed. You need to set these properties to match your installation:
`<properties>
    <!-- You have to change this! -->
    <path.installation.gurobi>/Library/gurobi751</path.installation.gurobi>
    <path.jar.gurobi>${path.installation.gurobi}/mac64/lib/gurobi.jar</path.jar.gurobi>
    <path.native.gurobi>${path.installation.gurobi}/mac64/bin</path.native.gurobi>
</properties>`

In my POM, I do not see these properties. I assume the author means these properties are there in his project POM. But how can I edit that?

Thank you for any help. Apologies for my ignorance with POMs and Maven

Comment: Can't you just define those properties in your pom? to override/change the values from the ojAlgo-gurobi pom.

Comment: Thank you. I am not very familiar with POM but now I understand what you meant in the GitHub wiki

Comment: @apete One more question: What is the fallback criterion for switching to Gurobi instead of OjAlgo solver? Can I have a time tolerance (say 50 s) after which it should fallback to Gurobi in case a solution is not found in 50 s. This part is not clear on Github

Comment: No, it doesn’t work like that. Only 1 solver will be used. Preferred or fallback relates to the logic of choosing which solver.

Comment: @apete Sorry but can you please explain (preferably with a short example) the fallback mode? Does it mean that in the fallback mode Gurobi will never be used?

Comment: Essentially yes, but it depends on if the built-in solvers can handle the problem type or not. Check this method: ExpressionsBasedModel#getIntegration()
That method decides which solver to use.